# Is there any way to try for badges like archaeologist without being annoying?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've been trying for various badges recently, and a lot of them are very good (like encouraging you to try chat, encouraging you to vote). I recently tried unsuccessfully for the '[tumbleweed](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/40/tumbleweed)' badge (at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411641/51970), which I realize now is a bad idea.

After that experience I realized that some badges cause serious annoyance. Specifically, the [archaeologist](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/127/archaeologist) badge. 100 posts is a lot, and it seems that people don't like old questions popping up on the front page for trivial reasons. Is there any way to try for the archaeologist badge in a constructive way, or is it one that should be left alone? Are there any other badges better left unsought?

Comment: "Is there any way to try for the archaeologist badge in a constructive way." - certainly; edit old posts as you encounter them, if need be. This is not a badge you're supposed to acquire on short notice.

Comment: A [relevant query on Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/109016/archaeologist-badge-accurate).

Comment: I have to confess that I only started posting on meta in the first place for badges... But it's been very helpful!

Comment: @Lord_Farin That query returns number higher than 100 for several users that do not have the [archaeologist badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/127/archaeologist).
Examples:[8297](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/109016/archaeologist-badge-accurate?userid=8297), [9849](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/109016/archaeologist-badge-accurate?userid=9849),
[30938](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/109016/archaeologist-badge-accurate?userid=30938). Several queries are mentioned in this [meta.SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161174/).

Comment: @Martin You are right; on closer inspection, that probably occurred because if you edit tags, title, and body, the edit gets registered three times. The keyword `DISTINCT` should solve this. My query (listing all relevant edits with links) is [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/119332).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can offset the potential annoying effect of edits by removing something even more annoying. For example, nondescriptive titles*

- [Analysis question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=analysis+question)
- [Algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=algebra+question)
- [Probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+probability+question)
- [Topology question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=topology+question)
- [Number theory question](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=number+theory+question)

(*) when necessary, fixing tags and body of the question at the same time.

I, for one, promise not to get  upset by any number of edits of this kind.

Comment: But as with any mass editing, be sure not to overdo it. Edit just a couple at a time, and keep a few hours (or even a day) between each sequential edits.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess my attitude toward edits may be more *laissez-faire* than most because I never look at the front page... Feel free to edit your amendment in.